# Undefined variable: profile_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm a beginner in php coding. i want to view profile information that can retrieve information from database. but i'm having error in my coding. Please help me solve this problem.

**this is my code**

```
   <?php 
    include 'connection.php';
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $get_user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    if ($get_user->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $profile_data = $get_user->fetch_assoc();

    }

    } 
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>    
    <head>        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title><?php echo $profile_data['username'] ?>'s Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a> | <?php echo $profile_data['username'] ?>'s Profile        
        <h3>Personal Information | <?php            $visitor = $_SESSION['username'];
               if ($username == $visitor)
    { ?>            <a href="edit-profile.php?user=<?php echo $profile_data['username'] ?>">Edit Profile</a>            <?php
    }
            ?>        </h3>        
            <table>
                        <tr>                
                            <td>Email:</td><td><?php echo $profile_data['email'] ?></td>   
                        </tr>
                        <tr>                
                            <td>Phone number:</td><td><?php echo $profile_data['phone_number'] ?></td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address:</td><td><?php echo $profile_data['address'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>State:</td><td><?php echo $profile_data['state'] ?></td> 
                        </tr>        
            </table> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

**this is my error**

```
Home |
Notice: Undefined variable: profile_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 22
's Profile
Personal Information |
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 24
Edit Profile
Email:  
Notice: Undefined variable: profile_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 30
Phone number:   
Notice: Undefined variable: profile_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 33
Address:    
Notice: Undefined variable: profile_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 36
State:  
Notice: Undefined variable: profile_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auto\profile.php on line 39
?>
```

Comment: This line `if ($get_user->num_rows == 1)` has to be failing, as it's the only place `$profile_data` is assigned in your code.

Comment: You should be adding proper debugging. If `if ($get_user->num_rows == 1)` returns false, the variable will never be defined. Without any debugging, you have no idea if MySQL is returning any errors, rows or how many rows for that matter.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter or `isset($_POST['username'])` might simply not be true.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice it was nested.

Comment: do you have a solution to correct this error. i have been trying so many time. but there is no changes.